# PostgreSQL query has = operators inside SELECT column references, what does this syntax mean?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

SQLALchemy generated the following query for me:

```
SELECT count(client.id = user_accounting_journal_entry.client_id) AS count_1 
FROM client, user_accounting_journal_entry
WHERE user_accounting_journal_entry.kind = 'debit' 
GROUP BY client.name = user_accounting_journal_entry.client_id
```

Note the part inside select: `count(client.id = user_accounting_journal_entry.client_id)`.

Having mostly used MySQL, I am not familiar with this syntax, and have a hard time finding documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be familiar with the syntax from MySQL, at least in this form:

```
select sum(client.id = user_accounting_journal_entry.client_id)
```

This would count the number of matches.

The `count()` version counts the number of times that the expression is not `NULL`.  Or equivalent, it counts the number of times that both values are not `NULL` . . . something that seems really strange.  More commonly in Postgres, I would expect:

```
select sum((client.id = user_accounting_journal_entry.client_id)::int)
```

This converts the boolean to an integer and hence counts the number of matches.

The query itself is awful:

- It doesn't use proper `join` syntax
- The `join` conditions between the tables don't look correct (a name to an id)
- It is grouping by a boolean condition

In addition, it doesn't look like it is doing something that is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

count(client.id = user_accounting_journal_entry.client_id) count number of times expression is not null.